# Perl- Script time calculator

Tags: perl

Need help on this.

I would like to create a script that will receive  2 parameters (time) with following format `AA:BB` (AA goes from 00 to 200 and BB from 0 to 59).

And it should add those to time and give the results, if the result is more than 24 h, it make it 1 day, if it is more than 7 days a week.

For example, 23:03 11:05 will give 1 day and 10:08, and 35:05 162:01 will give 1 week, 1 day and 5:06.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question. What problem are you having?

Comment: Note: Not all days have 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Before we start, I want to remind you that not every day is 24 hours long. The length of a day can be 22, 23, 24, 25 or 26 hours. This means that what you want to do will inherently add errors to your data.

I'd normally be the first to instruct you to use a module, because a good date/time module is designed to prevent you from doing exactly what you ask for. That means it's easier to solve your problem from scratch rather that using a module. In fact, it's not even possible to do what you want with the module I normally use, DateTime.

```
my ($hours1, $minutes1) = split /:/, $arg1;
my ($hours2, $minutes2) = split /:/, $arg2;

my $hours   = $hours1   + $hours2;
my $minutes = $minutes1 + $minutes2;

$hours   += ($minutes - ($minutes % 60)) / 60;  $minutes %= 60;
my $days  = ($hours   - ($hours   % 24)) / 24;  $hours   %= 24;
my $weeks = ($days    - ($days    %  7)) /  7;  $days    %=  7;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use these two: [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime) and [DateTime::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DateTime%3a%3aDuration).

With the first you can represent the *date*, and with the second the amount of *time* you want to add. Then, look at the `add_duration` method in `DateTime`.

Comment: The `add()` method creates a duration object for you.

Comment: You'll want to use the `time_zone => 'floating'`

Comment: How would you do this with DateTime and/or DateTime::Duration? I don't think it's possible, even with `floating`.

Comment: You could use DateTime::Duration if you were really motivated, kinda...  You could use it to convert the inputs into hours & minutes, then manually convert hours into days and make a second Duration object to do the conversion to weeks/days.  But really, this looks like a homework assignment designed to teach modular arithmetic rather than a "real" problem.