# Add time script Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to create a script that will receive 2  paramerters (hours and minutes) ( HH1:MN1 and HH2:MN2)

- It has to valid if the #ARGV = 2
- Valide if the time provide is correct (hours between 0 to 200 and minutes between 0 to 59)
- Add those thow time and print to results
- If it is more than 24 hr to print Nbday; HH:Min
- if it is more than 7 days it will print Week; nddays; HH:Min.

I started with this but cant figureout how to continue
Any help or idea will be welcomed for the calculation
Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ($#ARGV != 2)
{
print STDERR "Erreur Parameters have to be 2\n";
exit (-1);
}
if ($ARGV[0] = ~ / ([0-9] | 1 [0-9] ? [0-9] | 200 ) : ( [0-5] ? [0-9] ) /)
{
$heures1 = $1;
$minutes1 = $2;
}
else 
{
print STDERR "first parameter invalid\";
exit (-1);
}
if ($ARGV[1] = ~ / ([0-9] | 1 [0-9] ? [0-9] | 200 ) : ( [0-5] ? [0-9] ) /)
{
$heures2 = $3;
$minutes2 = $4;
}
`else `
{
print STDERR "Second parameter  invalid\";
exit (-1);
$heures = $heures1 + $heures2;
$minutes = $minutes1 + $minutes2'
```

Answer (score 2):

The validation code is pretty straightforward:

```
sub usage {
   print STDERR $_[0] if @_;
   print STDERR "usage: ...\n";
   exit(1);
}

usage() if @ARGV != 2;

my ($hours1, $minutes1) = $ARGV[1] =~ /^([0-9]+):([0-9]+)\z/ or usage();
my ($hours2, $minutes2) = $ARGV[1] =~ /^([0-9]+):([0-9]+)\z/ or usage();

0 <= $hours1   && $hours1   <= 200 or usage("Invalid number of hours for first argument\n");
0 <= $minutes1 && $minutes1 <=  59 or usage("Invalid number of minutes for first argument\n");
0 <= $hours2   && $hours2   <= 200 or usage("Invalid number of hours for second argument\n");
0 <= $minutes2 && $minutes2 <=  59 or usage("Invalid number of minutes for second argument\n");
```

The range check can be done by regex, but it's error prone and unreadable.

```
/^0*(0|1[0-9]{0,2}|2(?:00?|[1-9])?|[3-9][0-9]?):0*(0|[1-5][0-9]?|[6-9])\z/
```

(The regex could be a little simpler, but it's written to virtually eliminate the possibility of backtracking.)

You already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627991/perl-script-time-calculator) and we gracefully provided solutions to the math part, so why are you asking again?

```
my ($hours1, $minutes1) = split /:/, $arg1;
my ($hours2, $minutes2) = split /:/, $arg2;

my $hours   = $hours1   + $hours2;
my $minutes = $minutes1 + $minutes2;

$hours   += ($minutes - ($minutes % 60)) / 60;  $minutes %= 60;
my $days  = ($hours   - ($hours   % 24)) / 24;  $hours   %= 24;
my $weeks = ($days    - ($days    %  7)) /  7;  $days    %=  7;
```

As for the output part, you should be able to manage on your own. One useful tip:

```
sprintf('%02d', $minutes)   # 0-padded to two digits
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

die "Erreur Parameters have to be 2" if (scalar(@ARGV) != 2) 

if ($ARGV[0] =~ /^([0-9]|1[0-9]?[0-9]|200):([0-5]?[0-9])$/) {
    $heures1 = $1;
    $minutes1 = $2;
} else {
    die "first parameter invalid";
}

if ($ARGV[1] =~ /^([0-9]|1[0-9]?[0-9]|200):([0-5]?[0-9])$/) {
    $heures2 = $3;
    $minutes2 = $4;
} else {
    die "Second parameter invalid";
}

$heures = $heures1 + $heures2;
$minutes = $minutes1 + $minutes2'
```

Comment: `my ($heures1, $minutes1) = $ARGV[0] =~ /^([0-9]|1[0-9]?[0-9]|200):([0-5]?[0-9])$/
   or die "first parameter invalid";` doesn't use globals and only takes two lines instead of seven.

Comment: `(scalar(@ARGV) != 2)` is a complicated way of writing `@ARGV != 2`.

Comment: You're disallowing 20:00. This goes to show that regex is not the way to go for range checks. It's easy to get wrong, and it's unreadable (as evidenced that you didn't notice that 20:00 doesn't match).